# WordPress: Count child pages

Tags: php, wordpress, count

On a page in WordPress, I want to display all childrens of that page. This works at the moment like this:

```
<?php 
$args = array( 
'post_type'      => 'page', 
'posts_per_page' => -1, 
'post_parent'    => $post->ID, 
'order'          => 'ASC', 
'orderby'        => 'menu_order' 
); 
$parent = new WP_Query( $args );            
if ( $parent->have_posts() ) : ?>               
<?php while ( $parent->have_posts() ) : $parent->the_post(); ?>             
    <div id="parent-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="parent-page">            
        <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1> 
    </div> 
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

What I want is that the loop counts my posts and prints the number in the div, starting with 1. For example:

```
<div class="child1">
    Title of first child
</div>
<div class="child2">
    Title of second child
</div>
<div class="child3">
    Title of third child
</div>
```

What are your suggestions?

Comment: It's not clear what you need help with. It seems as though you simply need to modify the markup within the loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a `$count` variable and increment it each time through the loop.

```
<?php $count = 1; ?>
<?php while ( $parent->have_posts() ) : $parent->the_post(); ?>             
    <div id="parent-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="parent-page child<?php echo $count++; ?>">            
        <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1> 
    </div> 
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Great, that's it :)